# optparse does not save second whitespace into arg

Tags: python, regex, optparse

I am writing a regex match program, and I am unable to use regular expressions that start with spaces.

Is there any way to tell OptParse to only delimit by the first whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the *shell* removes those spaces, not optparse. Python is handed a list of already-parsed command-line parameters.

Use quoting to preserve spaces:

```
./yourscript.py --option=" spaces in here "
```

To demonstrate, I created the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.argv
```

to show you what optparse sees:

```
$ ./demo.py     foo bar baz
['./demo.py', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Note how the whitespace is all removed and three values are passed to the script. But with quoting:

```
$ ./demo.py "    foo bar" baz
['./demo.py', '    foo bar', 'baz']
```

the whitespace is preserved, and I joined two strings together into one as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks alot of data to effectively answer it, but perhaps the following helps:

If you are unable to use a regex that starts with spaces, try using the replacement characters that represent spaces: `\s` .. So `\s{3}test` will match "<3 spaces>test".

If it is shell script, do remember to double-escape it since shell will otherwise just ignore the `s` in `\s`. So the right version would then be `\\s{3}test`

Answer (score 0):

The command-line splits the arguments before they get to your Python program. Depending on your shell, you might want to use `"` or `'` to encapsulate your regex. In Bash, for example, double quotes will enable shell expansion on `$` and `` ` `` characters, which might cause errors.

```
./match.py --pattern=" something (.*)"
```